# Startup service(pulseaudio) error

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio

Recently I've been trying to solve my issue with no success which is: I cannot make `pulseaudio` start on boot. What I did:

1. Went through threads and questions about this issue and doing what was suggested.
2. Ran this command(many times): `systemctl enable pulseadio` which gave the following error: `Failed to enable unit: Unit file pulseadio.service does not exist.`
3. Created a file named `pulseaduio.service` in the directory `/lib/systemd/system` with the following contents.

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Pulseaudio bizzare service

   [Service]
   PIDFile=/run/pulseaudio.pid
   ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -f /run/pulseaudio.pid
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start
   ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
   KillMode=process
   KillSignal=SIGQUIT
   TimeoutStopSec=5

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```

After running `systemctl status -l pulseaudio.service` I get this

```
    pulseaudio.service - Pulseaudio bizzare service
  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/pulseaudio.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2018-06-22 21:54:00 +04; 34s ago
  Process: 944 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Process: 930 ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -f /run/pulseaudio.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 944 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Tasks: 4 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/pulseaudio.service
           ├─ 991 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start
           └─1032 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulse/gconf-helper

Հնս 22 21:53:57 Moshniy systemd[1]: Starting Pulseaudio bizzare service...
Հնս 22 21:53:57 Moshniy systemd[1]: Started Pulseaudio bizzare service.
Հնս 22 21:53:58 Moshniy pulseaudio[944]: W: [pulseaudio] main.c: This program is not intended to be run as root (unless --system is specified).
Հնս 22 21:53:59 Moshniy pulseaudio[991]: Unable to contact D-Bus session bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
Հնս 22 21:53:59 Moshniy pulseaudio[991]: Failed to load module "module-jackdbus-detect" (argument: "channels=2"): initialization failed.
Հնս 22 21:54:00 Moshniy pulseaudio[991]: Module load failed.
Հնս 22 21:54:00 Moshniy pulseaudio[991]: Unable to contact D-Bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
Հնս 22 21:54:00 Moshniy pulseaudio[991]: Unable to contact D-Bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
Հնս 22 21:54:25 Moshniy pulseaudio[991]: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
```

p.s. My system is Ubuntu18.04 Desktop.

Comment: Please copy and paste the text from your terminal into your question!

Comment: The text from the picture?

Comment: Yes, I presume it's for your terminal!

Comment: The strange symbols at the beginning of lines are just armenian letters as my system locale is set accordingly.

Comment: Can we see a link the location where you followed their instructions

Comment: I didn't save it but I'll try to find it.

Comment: 1.https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/5233co/starting_pulseaudio_on_boot/

Comment: 2.https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1442424

Comment: 3.https://rudd-o.com/linux-and-free-software/how-to-make-pulseaudio-run-once-at-boot-for-all-your-users